# I need help retrieving files from this image

Tags: steganography

The person who sent this to me, says that there are some files in it, but I'm not getting anywhere. I looked at the hex with HxD trying to find something, there is information about the program the image was created (Photoshop), some ID's and stuff, I tried to compare with the file signatures, but I couldn't find anything really relevant. I tried lsb and I also put the image into different tools without success. (binwalk bulk_extractor foremost recoverjpg ewfacquire) Maybe I did something wrong with these, because I'm not very experienced, but that's what I have tried. Any help is appreciated.

[image: stego image]

Comment: Steganography mostly(?) uses PNG files and this one here seems to be JPG file. Either you have a wrong file, or site converts it to jpg. I am not sure but it does not help us to help you :) by the way there are many online decrypt sites. did you tried them?

Comment: Re: *"there is information about the program the image was created (Photoshop), some ID's and stuff"* - not in the version that we can download from this question. Perhaps the EXIF blocks got stripped off either before or during the upload to imgur servers? ... or perhaps as other comment suggests it's not even in the original format?